# how to set fillRect percentage

Tags: javascript, html

How do you set a percentage in a fillRect HTML/JS
               ctx.fillRect(50, 10%, 50, 40);
does not work how are you able to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just multiply the percentage by the height of the canvas.

```
ctx.fillRect( 50, .1 * canvas.height, 50, 40 );
```